# concept feedback for a multi-client server c++

Tags: c++, server, tcp

I am currently writing a server application that should instruct multiple clients.
I am unsure about the concept i have designed and would like to receive feedback on it.

There are several identical clients that record and process sensor data. In addition, the results are sent to the server so that the server can react if necessary and send new parameters to the client.
The client should continue to work after the connection has ended and try to reconnect at the same time. If there is no connection, data do not have to be transmitted subsequently.

My concept is as follows:

```
The client logs on to the server.
The client requests an initialization -> server ok.
The client requests parameter A -> server sends parameter
The client requests parameter B -> server sends parameter
...
The client requests parameter Z -> server sends parameter
The client sends initialization finished -> server says ok

endless loop
    Server queries measured value X -> client sends measured value
    Server sends parameter Y -> client says ok.
```

So first the client is the master and asks for the initialization parameters it needs, then the server and client swap roles and the server becomes the master.

Should the connection break, the client should reconnect to the server. but would then with the command:

```
The client sends initialization finished -> server says ok
```

start so that the initialization is skipped.

The request of parameters runs as follows:

```
Infinite loop
    Send (command)
    Timout = 1 second
        Receive
    if (! Timout)
        break
```

so i send the command and wait a little, if no answer comes i send the command again. this is shown here in abbreviated form. I wrote it in c ++ and I use several state machines. The state machines naturally also catch errors when the connection is interrupted and jump back to the initialization status ...

Since this is a multi-client application, I find it a little difficult. it runs as a single client. I have a class client in which a state machine and a socket are stored. the instance runs in a separate thread.
My problem now is, if the connection is lost, how can I establish a new connection (from an old client) to its instance (state machine). i would do this over some id comparison. so that the client sends his id first of all. (maybe also mac address ???)

I currently keep the connections to all clients open at all times. is that state of the art? or should you send a command, wait for an answer and close the connection again and then reconnect if necessary?

Many Thanks

Comment: `unordered_map<client_id, client_state>`?

Answer (score 0):

Once TCP connection is established
each side can send  for data.
Just that you have to get write -> read  sequence correct.
This can be easily implemented using non blocking socket IO.

> "My problem now is, if the connection is lost, how can I establish a
> new connection (from an old client) to its instance (state machine). i
> would do this over some id comparison. so that the client sends his id
> first of all. (maybe also mac address ???)"

One solution is each client has a UUID, Client must tell server every time it connects its ID , server can keep a map of UUID vs client socket connection.

If Client is lost server can delete the mapping. Both server & client can detect lost connection that should not be a problem.